# How to edit the headers of multiple fasta files from multiple folders?

Tags: fasta, bash

My directories are organized as follows: one main directory, in which I have multiple directories that end with a number ranging from 314 to 727, followed by .3   . For example, 'mgm4761314.3'. Within these directories, I have fasta files named after a similar pattern (for example, mgm4761314.3.299.screen.passed.fna is in the directory mgm4761314.3).

There is only one such file (.fna) per directory.

What I've been trying to do is to write a loop that would go through all these folders and fasta files, and add the short number associated with the folder/file name (eg. 314, 315...727) to the headers. For example, for my first folder/fasta file, instead of:

```
>seq1
>seq2
```

I want:

```
>314_seq1
>314_seq2
```

The output would be exported to a file called, for instance, 314.fna.

I've sort of made it work for one number at a time, but I have plenty of files, so I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with the loop part! This is what I tried (and it didn't work). Using ubuntu.

```
for i in {314..727}; do sed "s/>/>${i}_/" [...]/*${i}.3/mgm4761${i}.3.299.screen.passed.fna > [...]/*${i}.3/${i}.fna; done
```

Comment: This should be easy enough, but please [edit] your question to clarify the directory structure. Does this need to be done to _all_ files with an `.fna` extension in each directory?

Comment: @terdon Edited! Basically, there is only one file per directory (and all files are .fna)

Comment: Or could go perl -p -i -e 's/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close! This should do the trick:

```
for i in {314..727}; do 
    sed -i.bak "s/^>/>${i}_/" mgm4761${i}.3/*.fna
done
```

Note that I am using `-i` which makes `sed` edit the original file. Because I use `-i.bak`, this will create a backup file with the original data. Once you are sure the command does what you need, you can delete all of these files with `rm */*fna.bak`.

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction! However, there's something about it which went weird. It does what it's supposed to, but it also duplicates the headers. Example: '>314_NS500799:83:H53J2AFXX:2:11101:11350:1048
>314_NS500799:83:H53J2AFXX:2:11101:11350:1048
GGGCAGTCCTTGCAGGGTGATACAGTCACCGTTTCTCTGAATGGGGAGGATCGTCCCCAAACTGTCAAGTACTACCGTTTGGCCCAGATCGTCTTTCAGAACCCGTACTCTTCACTGAATCCGCGCAAGCCGGTGCGCGACATCGTCGGCA
>314_NS500799:83:H53J2AFXX:2:11101:2772:1050
>314_NS500799:83:H53J2AFXX:2:11101:2772:1050
etc'

Comment: IMO perl -p -i -e gives you more regex power, but this problem is easily solved just anchor the match and delete to the end

Comment: @Laura argh! That's because I'm an idiot and left a debugging command I had used while testing my answer. If you've run it already, you will want to rename all the `bak` files back to the original. You can do this with: `for i in */*bak; do mv "$i" "${i//.bak}"; done`. Then, run the updated command (without the `p` at the end of the `s///`) and it should work as expected.

Comment: @MichaelG. yes, `perl` is indeed better (and is where `sed` got the `-i` from), but overkill here. The match is already anchored to the beginning. The issue was that I had used `s/foo/bar/p` and the `p` causes `sed` to print any line where the substitution was successful. I was using that along with `-n` which suppresses output to test that it was working as expected, but forgot to remove it when posting the answer.

Comment: @Laura if you didn't keep the backup files, you can remove the duplicated headers with `perl -i -ne 'if(/^>/ && $_ eq $last){next}; print; $last=$_; ' */*fna`.

Comment: @MichaelG. Do you know, by any chance, how I could add a layer of complexity to this code? As in, instead of adding from a range of numbers that happen to be equivalent to folder endings, would there be a way to do this if I didn't know those numbers from before? I tried this to add codes from multiple folder names to the fasta, but...it's so bad that I'm not even getting an error message.
`for j in ${j}; do
        for i in ${i}; do
                sed -i.bak "s/^>/>${j}_${i}_/" mgp${j}/mgm????${i}.3/*.fna
        done
done`

Comment: @terdon is the expert on bash and awk. Personally I'd write a Perl script using glob, you might achieve it by piping.

Comment: Looking at your code, that is  alot  of directories why not replace ??? With *

Comment: @Laura I'm afraid I can't answer without knowing your directory names. But as Micahel said, `for dir in *` might be enough. You might want to ask a new question though where you can give us the relevant details (the devil's in the details with this sort of thing).